# How to compare two arrays which are in different functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app2 = angular.module("webApp2", [])
    .controller("webCtrl2", function ($scope, $window, $state, $http) {
        console.log("hi " + $state.params.usermail);
        $scope.uName = $state.params.usermail;
        $scope.useriden = $state.params.user;

        console.log("hbdhakkdjf" + "    " + $scope.uName)
        //$scope.data = $window.sessionStorage.getItem("Mydata");
        //console.log("data "+$scope.data);
        var usersList = [];
        var frndsAdded = [];

        $http.get("http://192.168.2.3:3000/userslist")
            .then(function (response) {
                usersList = response.data;
                //$scope.friendsList = response.data;
                //.................................................................
                $http.get("http://192.168.2.3:3000/sendfriendrequests/" + $scope.uName)
                    .then(function (response) {
                            frndsAdded = response.data;
                        },
                        function (response) {
                            console.log("error");
                        });
                // console.log("array print" + JSON.stringify($scope.usersList));
            }, function (response) {
                console.log("response");
            });
        console.log(frndsAdded);
        console.log("print userid" + $scope.useriden);
        $scope.addFrnd = function (frnd, index) {
            var data = {
                "userId": $scope.useriden,
                "requestname": frnd,
                "username": $scope.uName
            };
            console.log(data);
            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://192.168.2.3:3000/friendrequests',
                data: data
            }
            $http(req).then(function (response) {
                console.log("hjhuhjh" + JSON.stringify(response.data));
                $scope.usersList.splice("index");
            }, function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            });
        }
        $scope.logoutFn = function () {
            $state.go("signup");
        }

    });
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default well well-sm">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebChat</a>
        </div>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li style = margin-top:5%>
                <div class = "dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>Add Friends<span class = "caret"></span>
                    </a>
                <ul class = "dropdown-menu list-group" style = " overflow: scroll">
                    <!--<li class = "list-group-item" ng-repeat = "seeFrnd in usersList track by $index" ng-bind = "seeFrnd.username">name
                        <button class = "btn btn-primary" ng-click = "addFrnd()">Add Friend</button>
                    </li>-->
                    <li class = "list-group-item" ng-repeat = "seeFrnd in usersList track by $index"><span ng-bind="seeFrnd.username"></span>
                        <button class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click = "addFrnd(seeFrnd.username,$index)" class = "buttn" style="float: right">Add Friend</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            
            <li>
               <a href="#" ng-bind="uName"></a>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#" ng-click="logoutFn()">Logout</a></li>

        </ul>
        
    </div>
</nav>
<div ui-view></div>
```

I am doing chat application here I am getting two arrays.one is for users list and other is for friends list.both arrays are in different functions.I need to compare that both arrays.how could i do that?

Comment: if you store both the array in $scope variable then you can access it any where within that controller

Comment: I cannot see any array with the same friendsList. There is one but you have commented that. Would be great if you can paste some clear code here

Comment: i have taken usersList and frndsAdded arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.forEach(arr1, function(value1, key1) {
        angular.forEach(arr2, function(value2, key2) {
            //Comparison logic
        });
    });
```

Comment: but arr1 and arr2 are not in the same scope

Comment: are they in different controller

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Define the two arrays on $scope. You have to use your logic to compare two arrays inside the second API call after getting the second array values. If you want to do it outside then you have to wait for the asychronous API call to finish, so that you will get the complete array.

```
 $scope.usersList = [];
    $sccope.frndsAdded = [];
    $http.get("http://192.168.2.3:3000/userslist").then(function(response) {
        $scope.usersList = response.data;
        //$scope.friendsList = response.data;
        //.................................................................
        $http.get("http://192.168.2.3:3000/sendfriendrequests/" + $scope.uName).then(function(response) {
            $scope.frndsAdded = response.data;
            //Comaprison Logic
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.usersList.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.frndsAdded.length; j++) {
                    if ($scope.usersList[i].request == $scope.frndsAdded[j].request)
                    //ur logic
                }
            }
        }, function(response) {
            console.log("error");
        });
        // console.log("array print" + JSON.stringify($scope.usersList));
    }, function(response) {
        console.log("response");
    });
```